Do these triangles always exist in any cyclic quadrilateral?
Let $a,b,c,d$ be the sides of a cyclic quadrilateral and let $a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4$ be a permutation of $a,b,c,d$ such that $a_1 \le a_2 \le a_3 \le a_4$ and let $p,q$ be the two diagonals. Experimental evidences show that

There always exists a triangle with sides $p,q,a_4-a_1$
There always exists a triangle with sides $p,q,a_4-a_2$
There always exists a triangle with sides $p,q,a_3-a_1$

Can this be proved or disproved?
Related question: Does every cyclic quadrilaterals has two consecutive sides such that each of these sides and the two diagonals satisfy the triangle inequality?

This is a corollary of my proof that $(|a-c| , p, q) $ forms a triangle. Read that first to understand the context / setup of the solution. In particular, I established that $|p-q| < |a-c|$.
Clearly we have $ p+ q > \max (a, b, c, d) = a_4$, so it remains to show that $ |p-q| < a_i - a_j$ for the corresponding case.

WLOG, $a_4 = a$. Then $ |p-q| < |a-c| \leq a_4 - a_1 $.

WLOG, $a_ 1= b$. Then $ |p-q| < |a-c| \leq a_4 - a_2 $.

WLOG $a_4 = b$. Then $ |p-q| < |a-c| \leq a_3 - a_1  $.


Note:

It is not necessarily true that the other $(a_i - a_j, p, q)$ form a triangle.
This approach indicates that we look at $a > b > d > c $ for a counterexample to $a_4 - a_3, a_2 - a_1$, and at  $ a > c > b > d$ for a counterexample to $a_3 - a_2$.
It is late here and I might have made some errors. If so, please point them out.

